# Как вывести блок по клику рядом с курсором?

Tags: javascript

Кто может подсказать как вывести блок с данными из html атрибута по клику, рядом с курсором?
Я не силен в js, этот скрипт не выводит блок нигде.

```
var path = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
var description = document.getElementsByClassName('description').html($(this).attr('data-description'));
$description.fadeIn(50);

    path.onclick = function(event) {

      var pathCoords = this.getBoundingClientRect();


      var pathInnerCoords = {
        top: pathCoords.top + path.clientTop,
        left: pathCoords.left + path.clientLeft
      };

      var descriptionCoords = {
        top: event.clientY - pathInnerCoords.top - description.clientHeight / 2,
        left: event.clientX - pathInnerCoords.left - description.clientWidth / 2
      };

      if (descriptionCoords.top < 0) descriptionCoords.top = 0;

      if (descriptionCoords.left < 0) descriptionCoords.left = 0;


      if (descriptionCoords.left + description.clientWidth > path.clientWidth) {
        descriptionCoords.left = path.clientWidth - description.clientWidth;
      }

      if (descriptionCoords.top + description.clientHeight > path.clientHeight) {
        descriptionCoords.top = path.clientHeight - description.clientHeight;
      }

      description.style.left = descriptionCoords.left + 'px';
      description.style.top = descriptionCoords.top + 'px';
    }
```

Comment: А при клике в каком-либо другом месте должен пропасть? Или так и останется, пока не кликнуть на что-то другое из той же группы?

Comment: должен пропасть при клике в любом другом месте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ 1 ]** Простой вариант с кликом и зависанием на месте: Создаем блок с абсолютной позицией, добавляем в body и просто при клике выдаем позицию в зависимости от положения мышки (`e.pageX, e.pageY`).

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/hLzm67xs/)

```js
(function(){

var hint = document.createElement('div');
    hint.className = "hint"; // изначально невидимый клаcc
document.body.appendChild(hint);

var path = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
var i;
for( i = 0; i < path.length; i++ ){
  path[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    hint.innerText = this.dataset.description;
    hint.style.display = 'inline-block';

    /* Условие для координат всплывающего блока. 
    Через (e.pageX + Любое_Число) можно настраивать положение блока */
    if( e.pageX + hint.offsetWidth < document.body.offsetWidth ){
   /* e.pageX == расстояние от мышки до левого края страницы, в пикселях
      hint.offsetWidth == ширина всплывающей подсказки
      Если их сумма оказывается больше ширины body - сработает else */
      hint.style.top = e.pageY + 10 + 'px';
      hint.style.left = e.pageX + 10 + 'px';
    } else {          
      hint.style.top = e.pageY + 10 + 'px';
      hint.style.left = e.pageX - hint.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
    }
    /* 'e' - всего лишь переменная в фукнции... там могло бы быть
       function (bubu) { bubu.pageX; } */
  });
}

/* Добавляем событие 'клик' на всю страницу и каждый раз запускаем функцию*/
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  /*Если e.target (кликнутый элемент) имеет класс "path" - разворачиваемся*/
  if( e.target.className.match("path") ){ return; }
  /* А если нет - скрываем блок */
  hint.style.display = 'none';
});

})();
```

```css
path {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; border: 2px solid orange; cursor: pointer;}

.hint {display: none; position: absolute; border: 2px solid #045acf; background-color: white; z-index: 9999999;}
```

```html
<path class="path" data-description="11111">11111</path>
<path class="path" data-description="22222">22222</path>
<path class="path" data-description="33333">33333</path>
<path class="path" data-description="44444">44444</path>
<path class="path" data-description="55555">55555</path>
```

**[ 2 ]** Чуть более крутой вариант, всплывающая подсказка сразу при наведении: Можно было сразу всё напихать под `mousemove`, но он срабатывает после любого сдвига мышки... а каждый раз обновлять содержимое блока или делать его видимым - нет необходимости. Поэтому это дело прописывается под `museenter`. А к движению мышки привязаны только координаты блока.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/39d6jkbu/)

```js
(function(){

var hint = document.createElement('div');
    hint.className = "hint";
document.body.appendChild(hint);

var path = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
var i;
for( i = 0; i < path.length; i++ ){
  path[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    hint.innerText = this.dataset.description;
    hint.style.display = 'inline-block';  
  });
  path[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    hint.style.display = 'none';
  });  
  path[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
    if( e.pageX + hint.offsetWidth < document.body.offsetWidth ){      
      hint.style.top = e.pageY + 10 + 'px';
      hint.style.left = e.pageX + 10 + 'px';
    } else {          
      hint.style.top = e.pageY + 10 + 'px';
      hint.style.left = e.pageX - hint.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
    }
  });
}

})();
```

```css
path {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; border: 2px solid orange; cursor: pointer;}

.hint {display: none; position: absolute; border: 2px solid #045acf; background-color: white; z-index: 9999999;}
```

```html
<path data-description="11111">11111</path>
<path data-description="22222">22222</path>
<path data-description="33333">33333</path>
<path data-description="44444">44444</path>
<path data-description="55555">55555</path>
```

Comment: Как в первом варианте сделать закрытие блока при клике в любое место экрана, кроме клика по элементу path?
И еще вопрос, вот эта строчка hint.innerText = this.dataset.description; не видит блоков внутри атрибута, и просто выводит код

Comment: Дратути. Чуть переделал код) А `innerText` используют только если там должен быть именно текст. А если должен вставляться HTML-код (и работать как код), можно использовать `innerHTML`

Comment: Спасибо) Только теперь блок закрывается если кликнуть именно по нему, но не закрывается если кликнуть в сторону)
И можно ли сюда добавить условие, при котором блок не выходил за пределы экрана, а к примеру выходил с другой стороны курсора, если близко к краю документа?

Comment: `e.pageX + hint.offsetWidth < document.body.offsetWidth` — добавлено условие. Первое - это координаты мышки считая с левого края, второе - ширина блока-подсказки. Если их сумма меньше ширины всего body - нормально, если нет - блок перекидывается в другую сторону. А по кликам - подозреваю, что вы что-то в коде недоглядели, тут-то работает (под кодом кнопка 'Выполнить код'). Класс `class="path"` добавлен?

Comment: Кстати да, там не класснейм а тегнейм, поправил и закрывается в любом месте, но блин, при клике на descriotion тоже закрывается)

Comment: `if( e.target.className.match("path") || e.target == hint ) {...` — Дополненное условие... чтобы при клике на сам hint, тоже не закрывался. Через || можно сколько угодно таких добавить, это 'синоним' `ИЛИ` (условие делал для className, просто на случай если на странице появятся другие path... чтобы при клике на них - всё же закрывалось)

Comment: А мог бы ты на фиддл залить условие if( e.target.className.match("path") || e.target == hint ) {...?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/scra8kmz/

Comment: Почему то в моем случае (у меня еще div, внутри атрибута) скрипт работает сам хинт и его паддинг не закрываются, но при клике на внутренний блок внутри хинта, все окно закрывается)

Comment: А это дело возможно перенести в fiddle ?)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Grigory1994/xgf5aLyh/16/
Что смог)
Но тут так же по паддингам окна скрипт работает только

Comment: @Grigory1994  Ура! Нашел такое решение `hint.contains(e.target)` — такое условие проверит, если кликнуто в любом месте внутри hint. https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/w2Lx0sza/ При любом клике, `e.target` - является HTML-элементом, на который кликнули ( `e` - всего лишь переменная функции, там могло бы быть и `function(bubu) { bubu.target... }` ... )

Comment: Офигеть)
Большое спасибо, ты гений!
Сколько же всего мне еще предстоит выучить, много идей пока не могу применить в js)
Просто лучший=)