# не работает mouseover

Tags: javascript

```js
// А так должен работать mouseover ?
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onmouseover = function(){
  button.innerHTML = 'hello'
};
```

```html
<button class="btn">213</button>
```

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onmouseover = function(){
   var d  = 'text';
   return d;
};
```

```html
<button class="btn">213</button>
```

**Как сделать чтобы рядом с button появлялся текст ?**

Comment: @teran уже поправил :)

Comment: не ясно в чем вопрос. чего вы хотите от второго фрагмента-то? не ожидаете ведь вы, что если из Mouseover вернуть строку текста, то она вдруг будет написана на кнопке?

Comment: @teran поправил

Comment: дак добавьте рядом с кнопкой span, и по его id впишите туда текст.

Comment: @teran можно код увидеть пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быть может, так...

```css
.hint {display: none}
.btn:hover + .hint {display: inline;}
```

```html
<button class="btn">213</button><span class="hint"> text</span>
```

или так?)

```css
.btn {position: relative;}

.btn:before {
  content: attr(data-hint);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px; 
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.btn:hover:before { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<br><br><br>

<button class="btn" data-hint="Бубу 213">213</button>
<button class="btn" data-hint="Бубу 55555">55555</button>
```

А цитируя ваш код:

var button = document.querySelector('button');

```
button.onmouseover = function(){
   var d  = 'text';
   return d;
};

// Это то же самое, что написать 

button.onmouseover = 'text';

// т.е. не имеет смысла
```

Если хотелось сделать подсказку, которая при наведении будет всплывать и держаться рядом с мышкой и двигаться с ней, ссылаюсь сюда, на второй пример → [Как вывести блок по клику рядом с курсором?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987607/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/987619#987619)

Comment: Здравствуйте я хотел так как Вы сделали первый вариант

Comment: как можно сделать чтобы подсказка появлялась не только слева ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/m0xpygnj/ - как вариант... разместить их в общий блок, и наведение привязать к общему блоку (и позиционировать их как угодно).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];

let state = false;

btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  if (state) return;
  let newElem = document.createElement('div');
  newElem.className = 'tx';
  newElem.innerHTML = 'hello';
  document.body.appendChild(newElem);
  state = true;
  return;
});
```

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tx {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #512;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn">Hover me!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
  button.insertAdjacentText('afterend', "hello")
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">213</button>
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста почему не добавили смайлики для более удобного общения ?